# Sabre BargainFinderMax REST API Response returns less records than SOAP

Tags: javascript, rest, soap, http-post, sabre

I'm trying to implement Rest API for BFM(BargainFindermax) in my project where SOAP calls are already implemented and working. Since Soap does not provide pagination options, I was trying to implement the same flight search functionality with REST "BFM" API.

After integrating the Rest calls through javascript http.post request, Rest calls are working but the returned results in REST "BFM" call are fewer than SOAP "BFM" call. Fare prices returned in REST call are expensive compared to soap results as well. The request body of REST call is exactly same as SOAP i.e. Cabin type, passenger details, origin/destination information, currency etc. are all forming just as it was in previously implemented SOAP call. REST Call does not seem to return any record against "SisterOriginMilage.Number" either.

For some reason, Rest BFM returns different, fewer and costly Itinerary results than SOAP BFM. Any idea what could be the reason for these different results? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both API Interfaces are powered by the same core Air Shopping engine, so should not reflect in any difference results:

Validate the following are the same:

- Endpoints/environments you are hitting
- Credentials being used to assure same configurations are applied.
- SOAP vs REST Requests
- Time of requests, given Shopping response can differ on second by second basis.

If you can include the requests will help assist.